# Substrate POA and Validator Set and pallet_collection configuration error the trait `From<RuntimeOrigin>` not implemented

Tags: validator-set

I am configuring POA chain with validator set by :- https://github.com/gautamdhameja/substrate-validator-set/blob/master/docs/council-integration.md and trying to configure the collection pallet

I am using polkadot branch `0.9.30`

In my runtime I am trying to configure like this

```
parameter_types! {
    pub const MinAuthorities: u32 = 2;
}
type CouncilCollective = pallet_collective::Instance1;
type EnsureRootOrHalfCouncil = EitherOfDiverse<
    EnsureRoot<AccountId>,
    pallet_collective::EnsureProportionMoreThan<AccountId, CouncilCollective, 1, 2>,
>;

impl pallet_validator_set::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    // see readme for type declaration
    type AddRemoveOrigin = EnsureRootOrHalfCouncil;
    type MinAuthorities = MinAuthorities;
}
```

and in pallet_validator_set I have the following

```rust
//! # Validator Set Pallet
//!
//! The Validator Set Pallet allows addition and removal of
//! authorities/validators via extrinsics (transaction calls), in
//! Substrate-based PoA networks. It also integrates with the im-online pallet
//! to automatically remove offline validators.
//!
//! The pallet uses the Session pallet and implements related traits for session
//! management. Currently it uses periodic session rotation provided by the
//! session pallet to automatically rotate sessions. For this reason, the
//! validator addition and removal becomes effective only after 2 sessions
//! (queuing + applying).

#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

mod mock;
mod tests;

use frame_support::{
    ensure,
    pallet_prelude::*,
    traits::{EstimateNextSessionRotation, Get, ValidatorSet, ValidatorSetWithIdentification, FromContainsPair},
};
use frame_support::log;


pub use pallet::*;
use sp_runtime::traits::{Convert, Zero};
use sp_staking::offence::{Offence, OffenceError, ReportOffence};
use sp_std::{collections::btree_set::BTreeSet, prelude::*};

pub const LOG_TARGET: &'static str = "runtime::validator-set";

#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet {
    use super::*;
    use frame_system::pallet_prelude::*;

    /// Configure the pallet by specifying the parameters and types on which it
    /// depends.
    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config + pallet_session::Config {
        /// The Event type.
        type RuntimeEvent: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeEvent>;

        /// Origin for adding or removing a validator.
        type AddRemoveOrigin: EnsureOrigin<Self::RuntimeOrigin>;

        /// Minimum number of validators to leave in the validator set during
        /// auto removal.
        type MinAuthorities: Get<u32>;
    }

    #[pallet::pallet]
    #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
    #[pallet::without_storage_info]
    pub struct Pallet<T>(_);

    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn flag)]
    /// Flag to indicate to the session pallet if session should be rotated
    pub type Flag<T: Config> = StorageValue<_, bool>;

    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn validators)]
    pub type Validators<T: Config> = StorageValue<_, Vec<T::AccountId>, ValueQuery>;

    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn approved_validators)]
    pub type ApprovedValidators<T: Config> = StorageValue<_, Vec<T::AccountId>, ValueQuery>;

    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn validators_to_remove)]
    pub type OfflineValidators<T: Config> = StorageValue<_, Vec<T::AccountId>, ValueQuery>;

    #[pallet::event]
    #[pallet::generate_deposit(pub(super) fn deposit_event)]
    pub enum Event<T: Config> {
        /// New validator addition initiated. Effective in ~2 sessions.
        ValidatorAdditionInitiated(T::AccountId),

        /// Validator removal initiated. Effective in ~2 sessions.
        ValidatorRemovalInitiated(T::AccountId),
    }

    // Errors inform users that something went wrong.
    #[pallet::error]
    pub enum Error<T> {
        /// Target (post-removal) validator count is below the minimum.
        TooLowValidatorCount,
        /// Validator is already in the validator set.
        Duplicate,
        /// Validator is not approved for re-addition.
        ValidatorNotApproved,
        /// Only the validator can add itself back after coming online.
        BadOrigin,
    }

    #[pallet::hooks]
    impl<T: Config> Hooks<BlockNumberFor<T>> for Pallet<T> {}

    #[pallet::genesis_config]
    pub struct GenesisConfig<T: Config> {
        pub initial_validators: Vec<T::AccountId>,
    }

    #[cfg(feature = "std")]
    impl<T: Config> Default for GenesisConfig<T> {
        fn default() -> Self {
            Self { initial_validators: Default::default() }
        }
    }

    #[pallet::genesis_build]
    impl<T: Config> GenesisBuild<T> for GenesisConfig<T> {
        fn build(&self) {
            Pallet::<T>::initialize_validators(&self.initial_validators);
        }
    }

    #[pallet::call]
    impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        /// Add a new validator.
        ///
        /// New validator's session keys should be set in Session pallet before
        /// calling this.
        ///
        /// The origin can be configured using the `AddRemoveOrigin` type in the
        /// host runtime. Can also be set to sudo/root.
        #[pallet::weight(0)]
        pub fn add_validator(origin: OriginFor<T>, validator_id: T::AccountId) -> DispatchResult {
            T::AddRemoveOrigin::ensure_origin(origin)?;

            Self::do_add_validator(validator_id.clone())?;
            Self::approve_validator(validator_id)?;

            Ok(())
        }

        /// Remove a validator.
        ///
        /// The origin can be configured using the `AddRemoveOrigin` type in the
        /// host runtime. Can also be set to sudo/root.
        #[pallet::weight(0)]
        pub fn remove_validator(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            validator_id: T::AccountId,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            T::AddRemoveOrigin::ensure_origin(origin)?;

            Self::do_remove_validator(validator_id.clone())?;
            Self::unapprove_validator(validator_id)?;

            Ok(())
        }

        /// Add an approved validator again when it comes back online.
        ///
        /// For this call, the dispatch origin must be the validator itself.
        #[pallet::weight(0)]
        pub fn add_validator_again(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            validator_id: T::AccountId,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            ensure!(who == validator_id, Error::<T>::BadOrigin);

            let approved_set: BTreeSet<_> = <ApprovedValidators<T>>::get().into_iter().collect();
            ensure!(approved_set.contains(&validator_id), Error::<T>::ValidatorNotApproved);

            Self::do_add_validator(validator_id)?;

            Ok(())
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
    fn initialize_validators(validators: &[T::AccountId]) {

        assert!(validators.len() as u32 >= T::MinAuthorities::get(), "Initial set of validators must be at least T::MinAuthorities");
        assert!(<Validators<T>>::get().is_empty(), "Validators are already initialized!");

        <Validators<T>>::put(validators);
        <ApprovedValidators<T>>::put(validators);
    }

    fn do_add_validator(validator_id: T::AccountId) -> DispatchResult {
        let validator_set: BTreeSet<_> = <Validators<T>>::get().into_iter().collect();
        ensure!(!validator_set.contains(&validator_id), Error::<T>::Duplicate);
        <Validators<T>>::mutate(|v| v.push(validator_id.clone()));

        Self::deposit_event(Event::ValidatorAdditionInitiated(validator_id.clone()));
        log::debug!(target: LOG_TARGET, "Validator addition initiated.");

        Ok(())
    }

    fn do_remove_validator(validator_id: T::AccountId) -> DispatchResult {
        let mut validators = <Validators<T>>::get();

        // Ensuring that the post removal, target validator count doesn't go
        // below the minimum.
        ensure!(
            validators.len().saturating_sub(1) as u32 >= T::MinAuthorities::get(),
            Error::<T>::TooLowValidatorCount
        );

        validators.retain(|v| *v != validator_id);

        <Validators<T>>::put(validators);

        Self::deposit_event(Event::ValidatorRemovalInitiated(validator_id.clone()));
        log::debug!(target: LOG_TARGET, "Validator removal initiated.");

        Ok(())
    }

    fn approve_validator(validator_id: T::AccountId) -> DispatchResult {
        let approved_set: BTreeSet<_> = <ApprovedValidators<T>>::get().into_iter().collect();
        ensure!(!approved_set.contains(&validator_id), Error::<T>::Duplicate);
        <ApprovedValidators<T>>::mutate(|v| v.push(validator_id.clone()));
        Ok(())
    }

    fn unapprove_validator(validator_id: T::AccountId) -> DispatchResult {
        let mut approved_set = <ApprovedValidators<T>>::get();
        approved_set.retain(|v| *v != validator_id);
        Ok(())
    }

    // Adds offline validators to a local cache for removal at new session.
    fn mark_for_removal(validator_id: T::AccountId) {
        <OfflineValidators<T>>::mutate(|v| v.push(validator_id));
        log::debug!(target: LOG_TARGET, "Offline validator marked for auto removal.");
    }

    // Removes offline validators from the validator set and clears the offline
    // cache. It is called in the session change hook and removes the validators
    // who were reported offline during the session that is ending. We do not
    // check for `MinAuthorities` here, because the offline validators will not
    // produce blocks and will have the same overall effect on the runtime.
    fn remove_offline_validators() {
        let validators_to_remove: BTreeSet<_> = <OfflineValidators<T>>::get().into_iter().collect();

        // Delete from active validator set.
        <Validators<T>>::mutate(|vs| vs.retain(|v| !validators_to_remove.contains(v)));
        log::debug!(
            target: LOG_TARGET,
            "Initiated removal of {:?} offline validators.",
            validators_to_remove.len()
        );

        // Clear the offline validator list to avoid repeated deletion.
        <OfflineValidators<T>>::put(Vec::<T::AccountId>::new());
    }
}

// Provides the new set of validators to the session module when session is
// being rotated.
impl<T: Config> pallet_session::SessionManager<T::AccountId> for Pallet<T> {
    // Plan a new session and provide new validator set.
    fn new_session(_new_index: u32) -> Option<Vec<T::AccountId>> {
        // Remove any offline validators. This will only work when the runtime
        // also has the im-online pallet.
        Self::remove_offline_validators();

        log::debug!(target: LOG_TARGET, "New session called; updated validator set provided.");

        Some(Self::validators())
    }

    fn end_session(_end_index: u32) {}

    fn start_session(_start_index: u32) {}
}

impl<T: Config> EstimateNextSessionRotation<T::BlockNumber> for Pallet<T> {
    fn average_session_length() -> T::BlockNumber {
        Zero::zero()
    }

    fn estimate_current_session_progress(
        _now: T::BlockNumber,
    ) -> (Option<sp_runtime::Permill>, frame_support::dispatch::Weight) {
        (None, Zero::zero())
    }

    fn estimate_next_session_rotation(
        _now: T::BlockNumber,
    ) -> (Option<T::BlockNumber>, frame_support::dispatch::Weight) {
        (None, Zero::zero())
    }
}

// Implementation of Convert trait for mapping ValidatorId with AccountId.
pub struct ValidatorOf<T>(sp_std::marker::PhantomData<T>);

impl<T: Config> Convert<T::ValidatorId, Option<T::ValidatorId>> for ValidatorOf<T> {
    fn convert(account: T::ValidatorId) -> Option<T::ValidatorId> {
        Some(account)
    }
}

impl<T: Config> ValidatorSet<T::AccountId> for Pallet<T> {
    type ValidatorId = T::ValidatorId;
    type ValidatorIdOf = T::ValidatorIdOf;

    fn session_index() -> sp_staking::SessionIndex {
        pallet_session::Pallet::<T>::current_index()
    }

    fn validators() -> Vec<Self::ValidatorId> {
        pallet_session::Pallet::<T>::validators()
    }
}

impl<T: Config> ValidatorSetWithIdentification<T::AccountId> for Pallet<T> {
    type Identification = T::ValidatorId;
    type IdentificationOf = ValidatorOf<T>;
}

// Offence reporting and unresponsiveness management.
impl<T: Config, O: Offence<(T::AccountId, T::AccountId)>>
ReportOffence<T::AccountId, (T::AccountId, T::AccountId), O> for Pallet<T>
{
    fn report_offence(_reporters: Vec<T::AccountId>, offence: O) -> Result<(), OffenceError> {
        let offenders = offence.offenders();

        for (v, _) in offenders.into_iter() {
            Self::mark_for_removal(v);
        }

        Ok(())
    }

    fn is_known_offence(
        _offenders: &[(T::AccountId, T::AccountId)],
        _time_slot: &O::TimeSlot,
    ) -> bool {
        false
    }
}

impl<T: Config> pallet_session::ShouldEndSession<T::BlockNumber> for Pallet<T> {
    fn should_end_session(_now: T::BlockNumber) -> bool {
        Self::flag().unwrap_or(false)
    }
}
```

But when I try to compile the code I am getting following error

```
type AddRemoveOrigin = EnsureRootOrHalfCouncil;
      |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<RuntimeOrigin>` is not implemented for `Result<pallet_collective::RawOrigin<AccountId32, Instance1>, RuntimeOrigin>`
```

and I cannot configure this

```
type EnsureRootOrHalfCouncil = EnsureOneOf<
    AccountId,
    EnsureRoot<AccountId>,
    pallet_collective::EnsureProportionAtLeast<1, 2, AccountId>
>;
```

and seems its depreciated

How to configure collection pallet for validator_set and fix this  error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that in your runtime `lib.rs` file you have the following:

```
construct_runtime! {
   ...
   Collective: pallet_collective,
   // Or if you specify the parts manually
   Collective: pallet::collective::{Pallet, Call, Origin, Event},
   ...
}
```

You need to add the `pallet_collective::RawOrigin` to the `RuntimeOrigin` which is done by `construct_runtime!` when told that the pallet exposes an `Origin`.